# Some doubts about where a JQuery javascript is called into this example code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flexslider

I am a beginner with JavaScript and I have the following doubt related to this demo website: http://www.html.it/guide/img/bootstrap/demo/home.html

As you can see in the homepage header there is a SlideShow made usinge a **JQuery** plugin named **FlexSlider** that is created by this HTML section:

```
    <!-- Sezione slider con Flexslider -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div id="main-slider" class="flexslider">
                <ul class="slides">
                    <li>
                        <img src="assets/img/flexslider/flex-1.jpg">
                        <div class="flex-caption">
                            <p class="flex-caption-text">
                                <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
                                <br>
                                <span>sit dolor</span>
                                <br>
                                <span>adipiscing elitur</span>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="assets/img/flexslider/flex-2.jpg">
                        <div class="flex-caption">
                            <p class="flex-caption-text">
                                <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
                                <br>
                                <span>sit dolor</span>
                                <br>
                                <span>adipiscing elitur</span>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="assets/img/flexslider/flex-3.jpg">
                        <div class="flex-caption">
                            <p class="flex-caption-text">
                                <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
                                <br>
                                <span>sit dolor</span>
                                <br>
                                <span>adipiscing elitur</span>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /.flexslider -->
        </div><!-- /.col-sm-12 -->
    </div><!-- /.row -->
```

My doubt is: I have the HTML section that represent the slideshow and the **FlexSlider** Javascript is loaded by this line:

```
<script src="assets/plugins/flexslider/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
```

but I can't find where FlexSlider is called to build the slideshow?

I would expect something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.flexslider').flexslider({option1: value, option2: value});
});
```

What am I missing? Why it work?

Tnx

Andrea

Answer (score 2):

The code you'd expect to be there is indeed there. It's just in a separate .js file rather than in the HTML for the page. Two lines down from the `<script>` tag that loads the plugin is this:

```
<script src="assets/js/scripts.js"></script>
```

And inside of that file:

```
/* Slider */

$(window).load(function() {
 $('#main-slider').flexslider({
     animation: "slide",
     useCSS: false,
     pauseOnHover: true
 });
});
```